# What tools should I use for C# having previously been mainly a Java developer?

Tags: c#

I am new to C#, having previously been a Java developer.  I am used to tools such as Eclipse, JUnit and Ant - are there C# equivalents I can use - or could you recommend some of the most popular tools?  I've heard of Resharper and Nant.  Please avoid documentation tools as I have asked this as a separate question.

Also in your opinion which ones are best?

Comment: Definitely listen to the people telling you to use Resharper. Once you've used it you'll find it hard to work without it. It seriously is that good.

Comment: The downside of Resharper is that it can really kill performance with big solutions. In work, I'm running an AMD Athlon 64 3500 with 2GB RAM, and it slows VS down so much it's unusable. I typically have 3-4 VS windows each with rather large solutions (up to 100 projects).

Comment: @Joe, sooner or later your VS would slow down even without Resharper once you have too many projects in the solution. 100 projects is a lot - do you really change the code on the all of the projects all of the time? Why not split the solution into several smaller ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio replaces Eclipse. If you're a IntelliJ user, you should also install Resharper (although I recommend this even if you are not a IntelliJ user).

NAnt is the .NET equivalent for Ant

NUnit is the unit test tool of choice for .NET

Answer (score 3):

- IDEs: Visual Studio (Express), MonoDevelop, SharpDevelop
- Unit-testing Frameworks: NUnit, mbUnit, TestDriven.NET
- Build Automation Tools: NAnt, MSBuild

Answer (score 2):

IDE: Visual Studio (+ Resharper)

Unit testing: NUnit

Build: NAnt

Just stick an 'N' in front of your favourites and see if it exists ;)

Answer (score 2):

As a programming IDE you could use Visual Studio Express (free) or regular Visual Studio (costs money). SharpDevelop is excellent as well

Answer (score 2):

IDE -- Visual Studio + Resharper (worth every penny!)

Unit testing -- nUnit and Rhino Mocks, with nCover or partcover for coverage analysis

Code style -- MSFT's FxCop and StyleCop tools

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2008 enough for everything.. 
If you are just starter Express version should be ok for you.. (And it runs faster in my computer =) )..

Also, Resharper is really useful tool.